# Pass or receive parameter to onactivityresult android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera-intent

I have a camera application, with multiple camera button. The code for this is given below.

```
class btnTakePhotoClicker implements Button.OnClickListener
{       
    int k;
    public btnTakePhotoClicker(int k) {
        this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        capture_img = (ImageButton)view.get(k).findViewById(R.id.clickme);
        capture_img.setClickable(false);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);                      
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            capture_img = (ImageButton)view.get(cameraIndex[idx]).findViewById(R.id.clickme);
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");                                   
            capture_img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);          
        }
    }
```

Now i want to pas the index k to onactivityResult. Please guide how to do the same.

Comment: the really question is "why do you need it back in the onActivityResult". How can you override onActivityResult if your class not extends Actvity?

Answer (score 0):

Move `int k` to your activity class from your inner class. Then in `btnTakePhotoClicker` use `YourActivity.this.k = k`

Comment: Hi its not working as expected, i am calling this from different functions, can you suggest how to atleast return a string from onActivityResult if we cant pass parameter as an argument??

Comment: Hello guys, any inputs?? Its a little critical delivery!